# VBA code to merge two cells together

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2013

My scenario is a document with one two-column table. I am reading from a database and populating each row/column, but for some records, I want to merge the two columns into one cell and populate that as a row, then after that, continue the two column scenario. I want to issue a VBA statement to merge the two cells together to make one cell across the entire row. This is impossible to "record" as a new macro. I don't know what the row number is at run time, I only know the column numbers. My search string is: '"Word 2013" VBA table merge cells' but I get a lot of site that show you how to do it manually, not with VBA code.

My current code:

```
With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
.Cell(Row:=1, Column:=1).merge _
MergeTo:=.Cell(Row:=1, Column:=2)
.Borders.Enable = True
End With
```

In the document, I have a small table of one row and two columns. But I should be able to have a table of three rows with any mixture of columns, right? I just want to pick any two columns and merge them together to make one space, but at run-time I do not know what row number to provide.

Comment: My document is a .dotm template that contains a pre-existing table of one row, two columns. When launched, it reads from a database. As records are read, a new row is added to the table. If a certain database value comes up, I want to merge the two cells of the row into one cell for the row, and place a "header information" in that row. After that, I want to continue reading the data, the following rows being two columns again. I hope this is readable. It sounds so complicated, but my plan seems very simple.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821310.aspx

Comment: Thank you, Tim Williams, for your link. It doesn't work, though. I get an error: Run-time error '5941': The requested member of the collection does not exist.

Comment: Isn't this part of code which populates the table from a database? The code in the comment looks like it's being run on a manual selection.

Comment: I have the data part down pretty good; I'm at a point where I just need to massage the table as records are read. Most of the time, the records fit within a two-column model. When certain records appear, I want to do the merge thing to insert "header info", then continue with the two-column table data as each successive record is read.

Comment: The code in your question works for me.

Comment: "at run-time I do not know what row number to provide" - if you would show the rest of your code it might be easier to make a suggestion. Don't make us look through the keyhole - open the door !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this worked out, and I want to again thank you for your help. Here is my current code. The entire document is one two-column table, skinny, and includes hyperlinks so that it can be read and navigated on an iPhone. When a Unit value changes in the data, I want to 1) insert a new row below and merge it into one column, add a 'Go Home' link, then continue adding two-column rows.

The document is finally converted to a .PDF and accessed by iOS users.

```
    'Add a row for a 'back to home' link 
    If (intUnitOrder > intCurrentUnit) Then
       Selection.InsertRowsBelow (1)
       rowno = Selection.Information(wdEndOfRangeRowNumber) - 1
       With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
         .Cell(Row:=rowno, Column:=1).Merge MergeTo:=.Cell(Row:=rowno, _ 
         Column:=2)
       End With

       Selection.Tables(1).Rows(rowno).Range.ParagraphFormat. _
         Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
       Selection.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(230, 230, 230)
       Selection.Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
       Selection.Font.Italic = True

       ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, _
         Address:="#Home", SubAddress:="", _
         ScreenTip:="Go back to the top", _
         TextToDisplay:="back to Home"

       Selection.MoveDown wdLine, 1
       intCurrentUnit = intUnitOrder
    End If
```